# Приложение KivyMD вылетает при запуске

Tags: python, android, python-3.x, kivy, kivymd

Когда я открываю приложение в коде, все работает. Затем, я собираю его в apk, и оно собирается успешно. Но при открытии вылетает. Установить KivyMD из master пробовал.

Код:

```py
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen

# Загрузка KV-файла для дизайна
KV = '''

'''



class LearningApp(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.material_style = "M3"
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Cyan"  # Вы можете изменить цветовую палитру
        return Builder.load_file('dsg.kv')

    def start_learning(self):
        print('dff')

class Scr1(MDScreen):
    pass

class Scr2(MDScreen):
    pass

class helloworldpr(MDScreen):
    pass

class varpr(MDScreen):
    pass

class inputt(MDScreen):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    LearningApp().run()`
```

KV файл:

```
MDScreenManager:
    Scr1:
    Scr2:
    helloworldpr:
    varpr:
    inputt:

<Scr1>:
    name: 'Scr1'
    MDBottomAppBar:

        MDTopAppBar:
            title: "Выбор курса (1/2)"
            icon: "plus"
            type: "bottom"
            mode: "end"

    MDCard:
        size_hint: (.9, .3)
        padding: 15
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.8}
        elevation: 1

        MDLabel:
            text: "Уроки Python 3"
            halign: "left"
            valign: "top"
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.8}
            font_size: 32


        MDRoundFlatIconButton:
            text: "Начать Курс"
            icon: "rocket"
            text_color: "black"
            on_release: app.root.current = 'Scr2'

    MDCard:
        size_hint: (.9, .3)
        padding: 15
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.45}
        elevation: 1

        MDLabel:
            text: "Уроки Tkinter"
            halign: "left"
            valign: "top"
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.8}
            font_size: 32


        MDRoundFlatIconButton:
            text: "Скоро..."
            icon: "clock"
            text_color: "black"
            disabled: True


<Scr2>:
    name: 'Scr2'
    MDBottomAppBar:
        MDTopAppBar:
            title: "Выбор занятия (2/2)"
            icon: "plus"
            type: "bottom"
            mode: "end"

    MDRoundFlatIconButton:
        text: "Назад"
        icon: "keyboard-backspace"
        text_color: "black"
        pos_hint: {'right': 0.98, 'top': 0.98}
        on_release: app.root.current = 'Scr1'

    MDList:
        pos_hint: {'top': 1}
        TwoLineListItem:
            text: "1. Hello World"
            secondary_text: "Простейшая программа на python!"
            on_release: app.root.current = 'helloworldpr'
        TwoLineListItem:
            text: "2. Переменные"
            secondary_text: "Изучим простейшие типы переменных"
            on_release: app.root.current = 'varpr'
        TwoLineListItem:
            text: "3. Ввод данных"
            secondary_text: "Как ввести данные в программу и работать с ними"
            on_release: app.root.current = 'inputt'

<helloworldpr>:
    name: 'helloworldpr'

    ScrollView:
        size_hint: (1, 1)
        BoxLayout:
            padding: 30, 0, 30, 0  # Add top and bottom padding of 30px, and 0 for left and right
            size_hint: (1, None)
            height: self.minimum_height  # Make the height of the BoxLayout dynamic based on content

            MDLabel:
                halign: 'left'
                valign: 'top'
                text: ''' \n[size=32][b]1. Hello World[/b][/size]\n\n[size=24]1. Установка Python 3[/size]\n\n[size=16]Наверняка вы слышали про Python. Это высокоуровневый язык программирования, который подойдет для разработки сложных программ и структур. Так давайте его установим.\nДля установки перейдите на сайт [color=#2596be][u]www.python.org[/u][/color][/size] и выберите Downloads сверху сайта. Скачайте [b]Python 3.10[/b] (это самая последняя стабильная версия) И запустите установщик. [b]Внизу нажмите на галочку add python to PATH[/b], это пригодится вам позже. Затем нажми те install to current user и установите python.\n\n[size=24]2. Установка IDE[/size]\n\n[size=16]Что такое IDE? Это программа, где можно работать с кодом. У python есть встроенная IDE, но она не особо удобная. Я сам работаю в [b]PyCharm[/b]. Эта IDE [b]бесплатна для не коммерческих проектов[/b]. Перейдите на сайт [color=#2596be][u]www.jetbrains.com/pycharm[/u][/color] и скачайте последную версию этого IDE.\n\n[/size][size=24]3. Настройка IDE и написание кода[/size]\n\n[size=16]Откройте PyCharm, и создайте новый проект. Затем можно писать код. Зайдите в файл [b]main.py[/b] (или создайте его с помощью ПКМ -> New... -> Python File) и назовите его main.py. Затем напишите там одну строчку: [font=msr.otf]print('Hello World!)[/font], затем нажмите ПКМ в том месте, где вы написали этот код. Там нажмите на кнопку Run (если она неактивна подожите 5 минут и попробуй те снова) и вы увидите, что в консоль (она снизу) вывелось Hello World! [b]Это и была ваша первая программа[/b].[/size]'''
                markup: True
                size_hint_y: None  # Ensure that the label's height is determined by its content
                height: self.texture_size[1]

    MDRoundFlatIconButton:
        text: "Назад"
        icon: "keyboard-backspace"
        text_color: "black"
        pos_hint: {'right': 0.98, 'top': 0.98}
        on_release: app.root.current = 'Scr2'



<varpr>:
    name: 'varpr'

    ScrollView:
        size_hint: (1, 1)
        BoxLayout:
            padding: 30, 0, 30, 0  # Add top and bottom padding of 30px, and 0 for left and right
            size_hint: (1, None)
            height: self.minimum_height  # Make the height of the BoxLayout dynamic based on content

            MDLabel:
                halign: 'left'
                valign: 'top'
                text: ''' \n[size=32][b]2. Переменные[/b][/size]\n\n[size=24]1. Что это такое?[/size]\n\n[size=16]Переменные - это то, [b]где хранятся все данные приложения или программы[/b]. Тоесть, где вы можете хранить числа, строки и даже списки и словари. Давайте в этом разберемся.\n\n[/size][size=24]2. Применение переменных[/size]\n\n[size=16]Давай-те создадим простую программу для понимания.\n\n[font=msr.otf]a = 5\nb = 6\nprint(a + b)[/font]\n\nЭта программа выведет [b]11[/b].\n\n[/size][size=24]3. Типы переменных[/size]\n\n[size=16]В Python очень много типов переменных. Мы назовем несколько основных: [b]числа[/b], [b]строки[/b] и [b]списки[/b]\n\n[font=msr.otf]integer = 6 # число\nstring = "Привет!" # строка\nlist = [4, 'ffd', 'fo', [7, 75]] # список[/font]\n\nКод выше инициализирует все три типа переменных: и строку, и число, и список.\n\n[/size][size=24]3.1 Числа[/size]\n\n[size=16]Числа - это тип переменных, к которым можно применить все большинство существующих математических действий (пример одного из них был выше). Давай-те проверим это, создав простую программу: для начала, нам нужно инициализировать переменную: (мы назовем её a) \n\n[font=msr.otf]a = 34[/font]\n\nи вторую: b\n\n[font=msr.otf]b = 885[/font]\n\nЗатем, попробуем поработать с ними. Всего есть 7 типов математичексих операций в python (позже мы их разберем) но 4 основных это - [b]сложение[/b], [b]вычитание[/b], [b]умножение[/b] и [b]деление[/b]: \n\n[font=msr.otf]print(a+b, a/b, a-b, a*b) # сложение, деление, вычитание, умножение[/font]\n\nВ вывод вы получите результат всех этих операций разделенных пробелами.[/size]\n\n[size=24]3.2 Строки[/size]\n\n[size=16]Строки - это тип переменныхб в которых хранятся разные символы. Он обозначается знаками [font=msr.otf]""[/font] или [font=msr.otf]''[/font]. Например:\n\n[font=msr.otf]text = "тестовое сообщение"\nprint(text) # вывод: тестовое сообщение[/font]\n\nЭто самый простой способ применения строк. В будущем ещё поработаем с ними.[/size]\n\n[size=24]3.3 Списки[/size]\n\n[size=16]Списки умеют многое. Например хранить все типы информации внутри себя. Списки - это как список покупок, принципы очень похожи. Самый простой пример: [font=msr.otf]list = [11, 'Привет', 'мандарины'][/font]. Тоесть, списки содержат в себе много других переменных или информации. Списки [b]индекируются[/b]. Что это значит? Это значит, что списки можно перебрать циклом, или, например, достать оттуда второе слово: [font=msr.otf]print(list[1])[/font]. Но почему же я написал 1? Ответ прост: [b]списки в Python индексируются с нуля[/b]. Запомните это. Это очень важно. Тоесть, если я захочу достать второй элемент из списка, то я напишу [font=msr.otf]list[1][/font] а не [font=msr.otf]list[2][/font].[/size]\n\n'''
                markup: True
                size_hint_y: None  # Ensure that the label's height is determined by its content
                height: self.texture_size[1]

    MDRoundFlatIconButton:
        text: "Назад"
        icon: "keyboard-backspace"
        text_color: "black"
        pos_hint: {'right': 0.98, 'top': 0.98}
        on_release: app.root.current = 'Scr2'

<inputt>:
    name: 'inputt'

    ScrollView:
        size_hint: (1, 1)
        BoxLayout:
            padding: 30, 0, 30, 0  # Add top and bottom padding of 30px, and 0 for left and right
            size_hint: (1, None)
            height: self.minimum_height  # Make the height of the BoxLayout dynamic based on content

            MDLabel:
                halign: 'left'
                valign: 'top'
                text: '''\n[size=32][b]3. Ввод данных[/b][/size]\n\n[size=24]1. Что это значит?[/size]\n\n[size=16]Ввод данных от пользователя - одня из самых важных частей программирования: его можно встретить везде, от анкет до входа в электронную почту. Он нужен, чтобы получать данные, а затем обрабатывать их. в этом уроке мы рассмотрим ввод данных и дальшейшую их обработку.[/size]\n\n[size=24]2. Простой пример[/size]\n\n[size=16]Ввод данных в python осуществляется функцией [font=msr.otf]input()[/font]. Вот простой пример её использования:\n\n[font=msr.otf]print('Привет, ' + input('Введите ваше имя:'))[/font]\n\nВ этом примере у нас спросят имя, и после ввода имени и нажатия клавиши [b]Enter[/b] он выведет в консоль "Привет, " и имя, которое вы ввели.[/size]\n\n[size=24]3. Сложение чисел[/size]\n\n[size=16]Рассмортим более сложный пример применения ввода данных: сложение чисел:\n\n[font=msr.otf]a = input('Введите 1 число: ')\nb = input('Введите 2 число: ')\nprint('Сумма двух чисел: ' + (int(a)+int(b)))[/font]\n\nВ этом примере вы вводите сначала первое число, затем второе и программа преобразует их из числа в строку (кстати [b]все числа и т.д из input() выводятся строкой[/b]) и слкадывая их, выводит результат.[/size]\n\n'''
                markup: True
                size_hint_y: None  # Ensure that the label's height is determined by its content
                height: self.texture_size[1]

    MDRoundFlatIconButton:
        text: "Назад"
        icon: "keyboard-backspace"
        text_color: "black"
        pos_hint: {'right': 0.98, 'top': 0.98}
        on_release: app.root.current = 'Scr2'
```

adb logcat -s python:

```
09-27 11:54:49.453 16850 16883 I python  : Initialized python
09-27 11:54:49.453 16850 16883 I python  : AND: Init threads
09-27 11:54:49.454 16850 16883 I python  : testing python print redirection
09-27 11:54:49.455 16850 16883 I python  : Android path ['.', '/data/user/0/org.test.myapp/files/app/_python_bundle/stdlib.zip', '/data/user/0/org.test.myapp/files/app/_python_bundle/modules', '/data/user/0/org.test.myapp/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages']
09-27 11:54:49.455 16850 16883 I python  : os.environ is environ({'PATH': '/product/bin:/apex/com.android.runtime/bin:/apex/com.android.art/bin:/system_ext/bin:/system/bin:/system/xbin:/odm/bin:/vendor/bin:/vendor/xbin', 'ANDROID_BOOTLOGO': '1', 'ANDROID_ROOT': '/system', 'ANDROID_ASSETS': '/system/app', 'ANDROID_DATA': '/data', 'ANDROID_STORAGE': '/storage', 'ANDROID_ART_ROOT': '/apex/com.android.art', 'ANDROID_I18N_ROOT': '/apex/com.android.i18n', 'ANDROID_TZDATA_ROOT': '/apex/com.android.tzdata', 'EXTERNAL_STORAGE': '/sdcard', 'ASEC_MOUNTPOINT': '/mnt/asec', 'DOWNLOAD_CACHE': '/data/cache', 'BOOTCLASSPATH': '/apex/com.android.art/javalib/core-oj.jar:/apex/com.android.art/javalib/core-libart.jar:/apex/com.android.art/javalib/okhttp.jar:/apex/com.android.art/javalib/bouncycastle.jar:/apex/com.android.art/javalib/apache-xml.jar:/system/framework/framework.jar:/system/framework/framework-graphics.jar:/system/framework/ext.jar:/system/framework/telephony-common.jar:/system/framework/voip-common.jar:/system/framework/ims-common.jar:/system/framework/tcmiface.jar:/system/framework/telephony-ext.jar:/system/framework/qcom.fmradio.jar:/system/framework/QPerformance.jar:/system/framework/UxPerformance.jar:/system/framework/WfdCommon.jar:/system_ext/framework/miui-framework.jar:/system_ext/framework/miui-telephony-common.jar:/apex/com.android.i18n/javalib/core-icu4j.jar:/apex/com.android.adservices/javalib/framework-adservices.jar:/apex/com.android.adservices/javalib/framework-sdksandbox.jar:/apex/com.android.appsearch/javalib/framework-appsearch.jar:/apex/com.android.conscrypt/javalib/conscrypt.jar:/apex/com.android.ipsec/javalib/android.net.ipsec.ike.jar:/apex/com.android.media/javalib/updatable-media.jar:/apex/com.android.mediaprovider/javalib/framework-mediaprovider.jar:/apex/com.android.ondevicepersonalization/javalib/framework-ondevicepersonalization.jar:/apex/com.android.os.statsd/javalib/framework-statsd.jar:/apex/com.android.permission/javalib/framework-permission.jar:/apex/com.android.permission/javalib/framework-permission-s.jar:/apex/com.android.scheduling/javalib/framework-scheduling.jar:/apex/com.android.sdkext/javalib/framework-sdkextensions.jar:/apex/com.android.tethering/javalib/framework-connectivity.jar:/apex/com.android.tethering/javalib/framework-connectivity-t.jar:/apex/com.android.tethering/javalib/framework-tethering.jar:/apex/com.android.wifi/javalib/framework-wifi.jar', 'DEX2OATBOOTCLASSPATH': '/apex/com.android.art/javalib/core-oj.jar:/apex/com.android.art/javalib/core-libart.jar:/apex/com.android.art/javalib/okhttp.jar:/apex/com.android.art/javalib/bouncycastle.jar:/apex/com.android.art/javalib/apache-xml.jar:/system/framework/framework.jar:/system/framework/framework-graphics.jar:/system/framework/ext.jar:/system/framework/telephony-common.jar:/system/framework/voip-common.jar:/system/framework/ims-common.jar:/system/framework/tcmiface.jar:/system/framework/telephony-ext.jar:/system/framework/qcom.fmradio.jar:/system/framework/QPerformance.jar:/system/framework/UxPerformance.jar:/system/framework/WfdCommon.jar:/system_ext/framework/miui-framework.jar:/system_ext/framework/miui-telephony-common.jar:/apex/com.android.i18n/javalib/core-icu4j.jar', 'SYSTEMSERVERCLASSPATH': '/system/framework/com.android.location.provider.jar:/system/framework/services.jar:/system_ext/framework/miui-services.jar:/system_ext/framework/miui.services.jar:/apex/com.android.adservices/javalib/service-adservices.jar:/apex/com.android.adservices/javalib/service-sdksandbox.jar:/apex/com.android.appsearch/javalib/service-appsearch.jar:/apex/com.android.art/javalib/service-art.jar:/apex/com.android.media/javalib/service-media-s.jar:/apex/com.android.permission/javalib/service-permission.jar', 'STANDALONE_SYSTEMSERVER_JARS': '/apex/com.android.os.statsd/javalib/service-statsd.jar:/apex/com.android.scheduling/javalib/service-scheduling.jar:/apex/com.android.tethering/javalib/service-connectivity.jar:/apex/com.android.wifi/javalib/service-wifi.jar', 'ANDROID_SOCKET_zygote': '23', 'ANDROID_SOCKET_usap_pool_primary': '24', 'TMPDIR': '/data/us
09-27 11:54:49.455 16850 16883 I python  : Android kivy bootstrap done. __name__ is __main__
09-27 11:54:49.455 16850 16883 I python  : AND: Ran string
09-27 11:54:49.455 16850 16883 I python  : Run user program, change dir and execute entrypoint
09-27 11:54:49.570 16850 16883 I python  : [INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /data/user/0/org.test.myapp/files/app/.kivy/logs/kivy_23-09-27_1.txt
09-27 11:54:49.571 16850 16883 I python  : [INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v2.1.0
09-27 11:54:49.571 16850 16883 I python  : [INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "/data/user/0/org.test.myapp/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/__init__.pyc"
09-27 11:54:49.571 16850 16883 I python  : [INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.10.10 (main, Sep 26 2023, 07:13:51) [Clang 14.0.6 (https://android.googlesource.com/toolchain/llvm-project 4c603efb0
09-27 11:54:49.571 16850 16883 I python  : [INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at ""
09-27 11:54:49.572 16850 16883 I python  : [INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge log fired. Processing...
09-27 11:54:49.572 16850 16883 I python  : [INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge finished!
09-27 11:54:49.575 16850 16883 I python  : [INFO   ] [Factory     ] 189 symbols loaded
09-27 11:54:50.523 16850 16883 I python  : [INFO   ] [KivyMD      ] 1.1.1, git-Unknown, 2023-09-26 (installed at "/data/user/0/org.test.myapp/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivymd/__init__.pyc")
09-27 11:54:50.566 16850 16883 I python  : [INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
09-27 11:54:50.585 16850 16883 I python  : [INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
09-27 11:54:50.611 16850 16883 I python  : [INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
09-27 11:54:50.628 16850 16883 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL ES 2" graphics system
09-27 11:54:50.633 16850 16883 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <sdl2>
09-27 11:54:50.633 16850 16883 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'OpenGL ES 3.2 V@0502.41 (GIT@43fc279f3a, I58833f8ed4, 1679659134) (Date:03/24/23)'>
09-27 11:54:50.633 16850 16883 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'Qualcomm'>
09-27 11:54:50.634 16850 16883 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'Adreno (TM) 610'>
09-27 11:54:50.634 16850 16883 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 3, 2
09-27 11:54:50.634 16850 16883 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <16384>
09-27 11:54:50.634 16850 16883 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <16>
09-27 11:54:50.661 16850 16883 I python  : [INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
09-27 11:54:50.662 16850 16883 I python  : [INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
09-27 11:54:51.013 16850 16883 I python  : [WARNING] [Base        ] Unknown <android> provider
09-27 11:54:51.013 16850 16883 I python  : [INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
09-27 11:54:51.020 16850 16883 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
```

Я пытался скомпилировать KivyMD приложение, но при входе оно вылетает.

Comment: Добавьте и ненормальные ошибки, что в logcat.

Comment: Все. добавил logcat логи

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я нашел ответ на свой-же вопрос. Если у вас такая-же проблема, попробуйте поставить kivymd==1.0.2 в requirements `buildozer.spec`, и все запустится.